# All possible combinations of coins

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I need to write a program which displays all possible change combinations given an array of denominations [1 , 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200] // 1 = 1 cent

Value to make the change from = 300

I'm basing my code on the solution from this site http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-7-coin-change/

```
#include<stdio.h>

int count( int S[], int m, int n )
{
   int i, j, x, y;

   // We need n+1 rows as the table is consturcted in bottom up manner using 
   // the base case 0 value case (n = 0)
   int table[n+1][m];

   // Fill the enteries for 0 value case (n = 0)
   for (i=0; i<m; i++)
      table[0][i] = 1;

   // Fill rest of the table enteries in bottom up manner  
   for (i = 1; i < n+1; i++)
   {
       for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
       {
           // Count of solutions including S[j]
           x = (i-S[j] >= 0)? table[i - S[j]][j]: 0;

           // Count of solutions excluding S[j]
           y = (j >= 1)? table[i][j-1]: 0;

           // total count
           table[i][j] = x + y;
       }
   }
   return table[n][m-1];
}

// Driver program to test above function
int main()
{
   int arr[] = {1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200}; //coins array
   int m = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
   int n = 300; //value to make change from
   printf(" %d ", count(arr, m, n));
   return 0;
}
```

The program runs fine. It displays the number of all possible combinations, but I need it to be more advanced. The way I need it to work is to display the result in following fashion:

1 cent: n number of possible combinations.

2 cents:

5 cents:

and so on...

How can I modify the code to achieve that ?

Comment: When you say: *1 cent: n number of possible combinations* do you mean how many combinations use the 1 cent coin? If so, add an array of counters and every time you get to `table[i][j] = x + y;` you'll need to update those counters

Comment: Yes, I need it to display information how many combinations can be for each coin. For example 1 cent: 1251251 combinations 2 cents: 432423 combinations etc.

Comment: Should counter array and coins array be of equal size  ? Each counter corresponding to one of the coins ?

Comment: @KoKsMAN If you have **working code** and want to get answers how to improve it ask at [SE Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) please.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ He's looking for a solution for a very specific problem, so it's on-topic here. No point in moving it to [codereview.se].

Comment: @shapiro yaacov Is there any chance, you could provide me with a code snippet of how would that work ? I have added following counters array    
`int counter_array[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }`

Answer (score 0):

**Greedy Algorithm Approach**

Have this denominations in an int array say, int den[] = [1 , 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200]

Iterate over this array

For each iteration do the following

Take the element in the denominations array

Divide the change to be allotted number by the element in denominations array number

If the change allotted number is perfectly divisible by the number in denomination array then you are done with the change for that number.

If the number is not perfectly divisible then check for the remainder and do the same iteration with other number

Exit the inner iteration once you get the value equal to the change number

Do the same for the next denomination available in our denomination array.

---

```
Explained with example
den = [1 , 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200]
Change to be alloted : 270, let take this as x
and y be the temporary variable
Change map z[coin denomination, count of coins]

int y, z[];
First iteration : 
den = 1
x = 270
y = 270/1;
if x is equal to y*den
 then z[den, y] // z[1, 270]
Iteration completed

Second Iteration:
den = 2
x = 270
y = 270/2;
if x is equal to y*den
 then z[den , y] // [2, 135]
Iteration completed

Lets take a odd number
x = 217 and den = 20
y= 217/20;
now x is not equal to y*den
then update z[den, y] // [20, 10]
find new x = x - den*y = 17
x=17 and identify the next change value by greedy it would be 10
den = 10
y = 17/10 
now x is not equal to y*den
then update z[den, y] // [10, 1]
find new x = x - den*y = 7

then do the same and your map would be having following entries
[20, 10]
[10, 1]
[5, 1]
[2, 1]
```